# Embed youtube VEVO videos

Tags: javascript, php, youtube

I've been having troubles embedding youtube VEVO videos. VEVO blocks the embedding on website but somehow directlyrics.com can manage to do that. Example link: http://www.directlyrics.com/jessie-j-flashlight-lyrics.html 
As you can see the video top right is a vevo video.

I found that the iframe gets the video from the website of the owner, example: http://c.yvoschaap.com/yt.html#id=DzwkcbTQ7ZE

Do you guys have any ideas how this is done?

Comment: What kind of trouble? What are you trying to do exactly? Just copy-paste an embed tag, or build it from a Youtube URL, etc? Can you post your code? "I'm having trouble" is a bit vague to help...

Comment: Youtube allows restrict embedding to specific URLs. DirectLyrics probably have a deal with VEVO.

Comment: I found out VEVO doesn't allow video requests from an IP-adres (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx). I tried the same standard embed script it on a webhost and accessed youtube from a URL (http://www.some.site) and now it seems to work like a normal video. Thanks for the responses everyone! :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. Go to YouTube's Video that you want to embed.
2. Click Share
3. Click Embed
4. Copy paste the iFrame to your site.

Example iFrame:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DzwkcbTQ7ZE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/8Lxtsdkn/